# How can I make a component "display: none" until the user has made their selection?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, conditional-statements

Working in react and I'm trying to get my component to NOT show up until a selection is made. Once that selection is made, I need other styling to be put in place as follows:

```
<p className={player.weight >= opponent.weight ? "text-green border-green" : "text-danger border-danger"}>{player.weight}</p>
```

Until the selection goes through I don't want anything to show; as of now, while `player` is `undefined` that conditional still runs and I get an empty border.

Are there any quick tricks I can use to check whether a `player` object is `undefined` and render nothing, and THEN render the way I'd like it to once a selection is made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for `player`:

```
{player && <p className={player.weight >= opponent.weight ? "text-green border-green" : "text-danger border-danger"}>{player.weight}</p>}
```

This syntax `variable && something` is equivalent to `if(variable){ something }`

So if `variable` is a [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value like `null`, `undefined`, `0`, then `something` is not executed.

It is a well suited syntax for conditional rendering in React

Comment: This worked! If you don't mind explaining how this functions as a check though?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
<div style={{ display: myVar ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
<p>your data ...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `style` attribute could be applied to `p` tag directly

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I was assuming that there might be other things in the component as well which are not mentioned in the question that is why I added a div

Answer (score 0):

In React, there is a render method and you can return null in case you don't want it to render.

For example

```
render() {
  const { player } = this.props;

  if (!player) return null;

  return (
    <p className={
      player.weight >= opponent.weight ? 
        "text-green border-green" : "text-danger border-danger"}>
      {player.weight}
    </p>
  )
}
```

Or you can do what the first poster did

```
{player && <p className={player.weight >= opponent.weight ? "text-green border-green" : "text-danger border-danger"}>{player.weight}</p>}
```

If `player` is falsy (null, false, undefined), the part after the && condition will not execute since the first portion is already falsy.

a && b - here if a is not b will not execute since both give the same response of false. In below case, if a = false, then it doesn't matter what B since expression will always be false. Thus, react doesn't execute the html part (which is equivalent to b)

```
false && true
false && false
```